# mysql - Keeping unique records after removing parent child relationship

Tags: mysql

In a mysql database, I have a business Unit table which maintain the hierarchy of a client's business units. Each business unit can have a parent and/or a child.

**products_client_1.business_units**

```
id  parent_id
1   
2   1
3   1
4   1
8   1
14  3
17  2
31  1
35  4
36  1
37  4
38  2
39  31
40  8
41  3
42  31
43  
44  43
```

Currently, I have a customerId table which maintains the customerId at a business unit level

**contacts_client_1.buid_customer_id**

```
global_id   customer_id bu_id   
ABC1000033  1812130     2
ABC1000033  1812130     54
ABC1000034  4049809     2
ABC1000035  5630631     2
ABC1000082  5707052     2
ABC1000082  1111116     54
ABC1000091  5813085     2
ABC1000091  5813085     54
ABC1000093  5208477     2
ABC1000115  5045891     2
ABC1000115  5045891     54
ABC1000117  6114245     2
ABC1000117  6114247     54
ABC1000117  6114247     1
ABC1000111  1234567     38
ABC1000100  9023456     43
ABC1000100  9023457     44
```

Going forward, I do not want to maintain the customer id at individual business unit level. It should be unique for a given globalId. For this I want to migrate the existing customer id data based on the following condition.

If a globalId has customerId for a only single BU, migrate it as it is without bu_id.

If a globalId has customerId for 2 BUs (they can be parent-child at any level), keep the customerId of the parent most available BU.

required table **contacts_client_1.customer_id**

```
global_id   customer_id
ABC1000033  1812130
ABC1000034  4049809
ABC1000035  5630631
ABC1000082  5707052
ABC1000091  5813085
ABC1000093  5208477
ABC1000100  9023456
ABC1000111  1234567
ABC1000115  5045891
ABC1000117  6114247
```

PS: 
**globalId are not overlapping among different parent most BUs.**

**business_unit table is under products_client_1 schema and buid_customer_id table is under contacts_client_1 schema.**

**The same code should be executable for different clients.**

**This is a one time migration.**

Need help in writing the query.

Comment: Do you want to delete rows in `buid_customer_id` table?

Comment: What determines "most available"?  In your sample data, please mark which ones need to be deleted.

Comment: I want the BU_ID column deleted. As of now, the primary key is Global_id + BU_ID. The customer_id is at BU level. Now i want to remove this constraint and store it at the client level. The existing data should be migrated to the new table which has only Global_id as the primary key.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. PS Read about expressing transitive closures in SQL. How deep can the heirarchy be--is is just those 3 levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are going to do with your data, but the following should help:

Show only rows which have no parent for the same `global_id` in the `buid_customer_id` table:

```
select child.*
from contacts_client_1.buid_customer_id child
left join products_client_1.business_units bu
  on bu.id = child.bu_id
left join contacts_client_1.buid_customer_id parent
  on  parent.global_id = child.global_id
  and parent.bu_id     = bu.parent_id
where parent.global_id is null
```

Examples:

- Row `(ABC1000100  9023456  43)` - The `bu_id` (43) has no parent in `buid_customer_id`, so there will be no match for the first LEFT JOIN and also no match for the second. Since all columns from the left joined tables will be NULL, `parent.global_id is null` is TRUE and the row will be selected.
- Row `(ABC1000100  9023457  44)` - The `bu_id` (44) has a `parent_id` (43), so the first JOIN will find a match. The second JOIN will also find a match, because a row with the parent BU and the same `global_id` exists in the `buid_customer_id` table. Thus `parent.global_id` is not NULL and the row won't be selected.
- Row `(ABC1000033  1812130  2)` - The `bu_id` (2) has a `parent_id` (1). The first JOIN will find a match. But tere is no row in the `buid_customer_id` table with `bu_id = 1` and `global_id = ABC1000033`, so there is no match for the second JOIN. Thus `parent.global_id` will be NULL and the row will be selected.

Now you can use this statement to copy (migrate) the data to a new table with

```
insert into new_table
    select child.*
    [..]
```

You can also go the other way. If you replace the LEFT JOINs with INNER JOINs and remove the WHERE clause, you will get the opposite result (all rows which are not returned by the first query). You can use it to remove all those rows from the table.

Delete all rows which have a parent row for the same `global_id`:

```
delete child
from contacts_client_1.buid_customer_id child
join products_client_1.business_units bu
  on bu.id = child.bu_id
join contacts_client_1.buid_customer_id parent
  on  parent.global_id = child.global_id
  and parent.bu_id     = bu.parent_id
```

Now the table `buid_customer_id` will contain the same rows which are selected by the first query. If this data needs to be in another table - just rename it. Then you can copy `global_id` and `customer_id` with

```
insert into customer_id (global_id, customer_id)
    select global_id, customer_id
    from new_table
```